# Metadata from RTSP Stream using MediaPlayer on Android 2.2

Tags: android, metadata, rtsp, android-2.2-froyo, android-mediaplayer

I have an mp4a stream using RTSP, I can play the stream, however, I would like to retrieve the metadata embedded inside the stream. I know that there is a MediaMetaDataRetriever class, but it is for API Level 10 (2.3.3 - 2.3.4) but I am using Android 2.2. Is there a way to retrieve the metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've checked and there's absolutely no solution to this problem, other than reading the stream myself. I've decided to parse xml instead, which works basically the same.

Comment: Is your solution to stream over http and parse an XML file populated with the media's details?